# Having problem to create a RCP project from eclipse-jee-helios

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am doing this for the first time i have eclipsejee-helios-3.6. I want to create an RCP project it doesnot ask me  **"Would you like to create a rich client application?"** it just ask me to make an activator class. when i do this i can see only one class in my project . I am following [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-RCP-1/tutorial1.html) example.
hey please give me any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my mistake i was selecting the wrong **Target Platform**.
 It should be the `"Eclipse version"` not `"an OSGi framework"`. Now its working fine. So always see for the `Target platform`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would suggest you a better tutorial, which I used to learn RCP development.

[Check it out](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) - it is the most up to date tut for RCP dev. (based on Helios)

It gives very detailed, easy to follow step by step instructions & some explanation about the ideas behind the framework.

Hope it helps!

PS. just checked: If you got your installation right, in the create new plugin wizard, you are asked if you want to create an RCP application right below the activator class input field
[image: screenshot of the wizard in a fresh install of eclipse helios]

Comment: that is what i was searching for .... you are seeing there eclipse asked you to "would you like to create a rich client application" but when i was doing it doesnt asked me like that.

Comment: Then I suppose there is something wrong with your installation. I've just downloaded a fresh copy of helios JEE, and I go to 
> New > Other > Plugin Project > Next > [enter the name] > Next 
And I get the same window I've sent a screenshot about

Comment: i have uninstalled that one and installed again now its working like charm and thanks for your concern.